# Strip all whitespaces in string and convert it to an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, whitespace

I'm looking for a way to convert a string to an array and strip all whitespaces in the process. Here's what I have:

```
        String[] splitArray = input.split(" ").trim();
```

But I can't figure out how to get rid of spaces in between the elements. 
For example,

input = "    1        2 3 4      5    "

I want splitArray to be:

[1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: First trim, then split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this `input.split(" ").trim();` won't compile since you can't call `trim()` on an array, but fortunately you don't need to. Your problem is that your regex, `" "` is treating each space as a split target, and with an input String like so:

```
String input = "    1        2 3 4      5    ";
```

You end up creating an array filled with several empty `""` String items.

So this code:

```
String input = "    1        2 3 4      5    ";
// String[] splitArray = input.split("\\s+").trim();

String[] splitArray = input.trim().split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray));
```

will result in this output:

```
[1, , , , , , , , 2, 3, 4, , , , , , 5]
```

What you need to do is to create a regex that greedily groups all the spaces or whitespace characters together, and fortunately we have this ability -- the `+` operator

Simply use a greedy split with the whitespace regex group

```
String[] splitArray = input.trim().split("\\s+");
```

`\\s` denotes any white-space character, and the trailing `+` will greedily aggregate one or more contiguous white-space characters together.

And actually, in your situation where the whitespace is nothing but multiples of spaces: `" "`, this is adequate:

```
String[] splitArray = input.trim().split(" +");
```

Appropriate tutorials for this:

- [short-hand character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) -- discusses `\\s`
- [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) -- discusses the `+` also `?` and `*` repetition characters

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String[] result = input.split(" ");
```